# How do you make a sticky nav bar change colour when you scroll to a desired div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am curious as to how you would make your sticky navigation bar fade into a colour as you scroll down to a certain point or DIV on the page.

I would like to have this so I can see the white  over the white background when I scroll to the end of my  div or at the beginning of the  div.

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Aesthetic Media</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>

    <a class="logo" href="#">Aesthetic</a>

    <nav>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav

    <div class="clears"></div>

    <div class="maintext">

        <h1>We're Aesthetic</h1>
        <h2>A Visual Agency from Niagara</h2>

    </div>

</header>

<main>

<h2 class="whatwedo">Expertise</h2>
<div class="whatwedobox one"><div class="icon"></div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet.</p></div>
<div class="whatwedobox two"></div>
<div class="whatwedobox three"></div>

</main>

<footer></footer>

<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">          </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body {
background: white;
}

header {
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
background: white;
background: url('images/main.jpg') center center;
background-size: cover;
padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
position: relative;
}

.logo {
position: fixed;
top: 33px;
left: 30px;
width: 200px;
height: 80px;
display: block;
float: left;
z-index: 30;
font-size: 1.8em;
font-weight: 800;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 5px;  
}

.logo a {
font-size: 1.8em;
font-weight: 800;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 5px;
}

nav {
float: right;
z-index: 30;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
right: 0px;
letter-spacing: .2em;
}

nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

nav li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}

nav li a {
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
color: white;
display: block;
font-weight: 400;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

nav li a:hover {
background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.5);
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-transition: all .3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.clears {
clear: both;
}

.maintext {
margin: auto;
width: 600px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 200px;
color: white;
z-index: 30;
position: relative;
}

.maintext h1 {
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 1.8em;
line-height: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .1em;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.maintext h2 {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 1.7em;
line-height: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .1em;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

main {
max-width: 1180px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}

h2.whatwedo {
text-align: center;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 1.7em;
line-height: 1.2em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .1em;
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Raleway' , sans-serif, Helvetica, Verdana;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.whatwedobox {
width: 30%;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid blue;
float: left;
margin-right: 5%;
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.whatwedobox:last-child {
margin-right: 0%;
}

.icon {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: url(#) no-repeat center center;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $(".maintext");
var offset = startchange.offset();

 if (startchange.length){
 $(document).scroll(function() { 
  scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
      $("header").css('background-color', '#B5B5B5');
   } else {
      $('header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
});
}
});
```

Comment: you are missing a **`;`** at `var offset = startchange.offset` this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare  `$(window).scrollTop()`  with `offset().top` of that div. `offset()` is a `method`, not a `property`. Hence, calling `offset()` will return both `top` and `left`.

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>=$("that_div").offset().top) {
   //do something here
}
```

In your code, try replacing the line

```
var offset = startchange.offset;
```

with

```
var offset = startchange.offset();
```

Comment: I don't understand... Are you able to take my code and show me where to put that?

Comment: Hmm.. still not working. I would like the whole of the navbar to fade into a colour once the scroll position reaches the .maintext

Comment: can you make a fiddle, pluker or demo here?

Comment: Okay! So it does work although I now need to adjust the size of my header... although I'm not sure how to do this without affecting the background image which I've removed in codepen... Are you able to fix this? http://codepen.io/uchmanowicz/pen/qEebbN

Comment: let me see, you can make a new question so that more people can jump into this an you can have quick solution :)

Comment: header seems to be okay, whats the problem you are facing

Comment: If you notice the background image is inserted in the header {} css... For some reason this JS only works on codepen which is confusing me... I want a bar that following along underneath the navagation bar... including logo when you scroll down to the maintext section... not sure how to do this.